# Keeping domain of Email but removing TLD

Tags: python, pandas, string-parsing

I am using python and I want to be able to keep the domain of the email but remove the 'com', or '.co.uk', or 'us', etc

So basically if I have an email, say random@gmail.com. I want to have only @gmail left in string format, but I want to do this for any email. So random@yahoo.com would leave me with @yahoo, or random@aol.uk, would leave me with @aol

so far I have:

```
 domain = re.search("@[\w.]+", val)
 domain = domain.group()
```

That returns the domain but with the TLD . So @gmail.com, or @aol.co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pandas [functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['random@yahoo.com','random@aol.uk','random@aol.co.uk']})

print (df)
                  a
0  random@yahoo.com
1     random@aol.uk
2  random@aol.co.uk

print ('@' + df.a.str.split('@').str[1].str.split('.', 1).str[0] )
0    @yahoo
1      @aol
2      @aol
Name: a, dtype: object
```

But faster is use `apply`, if in column are not `NaN` values:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

print ('@' + df.a.str.split('@').str[1].str.split('.', 1).str[0] )
print (df.a.apply(lambda x: '@' + x.split('@')[1].split('.')[0]))

In [363]: %timeit ('@' + df.a.str.split('@').str[1].str.split('.', 1).str[0] )
10 loops, best of 3: 79.1 ms per loop

In [364]: %timeit (df.a.apply(lambda x: '@' + x.split('@')[1].split('.')[0]))
10 loops, best of 3: 27.7 ms per loop
```

Another solution with [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) is faster as `split`, it can be used if `NaN` values in column:

```
#not sure with all valid characters in email address
print ( '@' + df.a.str.extract(r"\@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\.", expand=False))
In [365]: %timeit ( '@' + df.a.str.extract(r"\@([A-Za-z0-9 _]+)\.", expand=False))
10 loops, best of 3: 39.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: What happens to john@arc.nasa.gov, or rms@mail.york.ac.uk

Answer (score 3):

If you do

```
val = string.split('@')[1].split('.')[0]
```

Change 'string' for your email string variable name.

This will take everything after the '@' symbol, then everything up to the first '.'

Using on 'random@gmail.com' gives 'gmail'

If you require the '@' symbol you can add it back with;

```
full = '@' + val
```

Comment: you type faster than me.  Same idea.  Not sure why pandas is necessary, but that also worked

Comment: Yeah yours also worked but accepted his answer since it fit my needs better, but would've accepted yours had he not put his up. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

First split on "@", take the part after "@".  Then split on "." and take the first part

```
email = "this.that@gmail.com.x.y"
'@' + email.split("@")[1].split(".")[0]
'@gmail'
```

Comment: Solution worked but accepted @jezrael because he kept the @ symbol. Thanks though, and I realize I can just change the index on the [1]

Comment: @Kalimantan   I'm not a pandas guy.  It seems like it adds complexity.  But your problem is solved.   I added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

For posterity and completeness, this can also be done via index and slice:

```
email = 'random@aol.co.uk'
at = email.index('@')
dot = email.index('.', at)
domain = email[at:dot]
```

Using `split()`and `re` seems like overkill when the goal is to extract a single sub-string.